# FileReader: get file name

Tags: angular, observable, filereader

I have a FileReader with an Observable which looks like this:

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable<Object>(obs => {
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        if (file) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                obs.next(fileReader.result);
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
        }
    });
}
```

I use the content of the file in the subscription:

```
this.readDocument(document).subscribe(content => {

}
```

In the subscription, how could i get the name of the file?

something like this:

```
   this.readDocument(document).subscribe(content => {
        filename = content.getfilename;
    }
```

Is this possible? what could be a solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return it in the `Observable`.

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable<any>(obs => {
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        if (file) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                obs.next({
                   name: file.name,
                   result: fileReader.result,
                });
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
        }
    });
}
```

> Update 
>   Here is how i modified you `update_chart()` and it workz

```
update_chart(document) {
  this.readDocument(document).subscribe((file: any) => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'." when trying this.name = file.name

Comment: Set you Observable type to `Observable<any>`

Comment: yes, i now even exactly copied what you wrote here and the error shows up on this.name and this.result when using in the subscription

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-j08lo here maybe this helps you i tried to recreate the error in the chart.component.ts

Comment: Here is the [edited example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-qqm00). Take a look into the console after selecting a file.